# Unexpected T_FUNCTION in code, meaning?

Tags: cakephp, error-handling

<strike>I get an unexpected T_FUNCTION error on the $keyRows++ line.</strike>

```
    $mapArray = array();
    $unifiedKeys = array();
    $unifiedKeys = $this->query("select distinct FLOWSHEET_ID from FLOWSHEET_TEMPLATE;");
    $keyRows = 1;
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($unifiedKeys)) {

        $mapArray['Method'.$keyRows] = array(
                CaBase::KEY_MAPPING_LOGIC_COMPLEXITY => CaBase::LEVEL3_COMPLEXITY,
                CaBase::KEY_FIELD_LOGIC_NAME         => 'wsUnifiedKey' ,
                //CaBase::KEY_FIELD_QUESTION_ID      => $unifiedKeys($id_position))
                CaBase::KEY_FIELD_QUESTION_ID        => '$row[\"FLOWSHEET_ID\"]'
                );  //fixed error
        $keyRows++;
    }
    return $mapArray;
```

1) What does this error mean? I get it quite a bit and I'm not sure how to debug it because I don't know what it means.

<strike>2) How should I go about fixing the error? I tried adding $this->keyRows++, but that didn't work either. Originally I was getting a "Can't use function return value in write context" error on this line, but I changed the $mapArray[] line to brackets instead of parentheses and now I'm getting the T_FUNCTION error.</strike>

ERROR IS NOW FIXED. But I am still curious as to what the T_FUNCTION error means/what to look for when it comes up.

Comment: That doesn't look like CakePHP to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is ABOVE the $keyRows++. You didn't put the semicolon after an array. :D

```
$mapArray['Method'.$keyRows] = array(
                CaBase::KEY_MAPPING_LOGIC_COMPLEXITY => CaBase::LEVEL3_COMPLEXITY,
                CaBase::KEY_FIELD_LOGIC_NAME         => 'wsUnifiedKey' ,
                //CaBase::KEY_FIELD_QUESTION_ID      => $unifiedKeys($id_position))
                CaBase::KEY_FIELD_QUESTION_ID        => '$row[\"FLOWSHEET_ID\"]'
                );
```

Comment: Wow. I've been banging my head on the wall forever because of that.